# Calculating Monthly Money Expenditure From a Txt File in C

Tags: c, math, operation, read-write

How to make monthly and yearly calculations from a txt file in C language? I'm trying to make a C language read and write program, but I'm confused about how to perform operations from it. I'm confused, please help me

This is an example of a txt file that was written

```
Jaka 2022 12  10 50000
Juki 2020 10  12 750000
Jaka 12 10  10 4000
```

And here's the code that I made, it's still limited to calculating all total expenses, I can't calculate monthly and yearly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void input();
void count();
void monthly_expenditure();

int main()
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("====================================MENU====================================\n");
        printf("1. Input Data\n");
        printf("2. count expenditure\n");
        printf("3. monthly expenditure\n");
        printf("4. exit\n");
        printf("choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            input();
            getchar();
            break;
        case 2:
            count();
            getchar();
            break;
        case 3:
            monthly_expenditure();
            getchar();
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("thank you\n");
            getchar();
            break;
        default:
            printf("error\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
    return 0;
}

void input()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char name[100], year[100], month[100], date[100], money[100];
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "a");

    printf("Input name : ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Input year : ");
    scanf("%s", year);
    printf("Input month : ");
    scanf("%s", month);
    printf("Input date : ");
    scanf("%s", date);
    printf("Input money : ");
    scanf("%s", money);
    fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s  %s %s\n", name, year, month, date, money);
    fclose(fp);
}

void count()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char name[100], year[100], month[100], date[100], money[100];
    int total = 0;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s %s", name, year, month, date, money) != EOF)
    {
        total += atoi(money);
    }
    printf("Total expenditure : %d\n", total);
    fclose(fp);
}

void monthly_expenditure(){

}
void year_expenditure(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one function that passes in the desired year and month.

Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of input, then parse.  This has far better error handling.

Do not test against `EOF`, one of the many return values from `*scanf()` that you do not want.  Test against the return value you want.

Use `int` for year, month, day.

Use a *width* with `%s` to avoid buffer overflow.

Recommend a wider type for money.

Illustrative *untested code*:

```
// Filter per year.  Use 0 for all years, all months 
// Return error code.
int count_filter(int year, int month) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) { 
    return 1;
  }

  long total = 0;
  char buf[200];// Some large buffer 

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
    char name[100];
    int y, m, d;
    long money;
    if (sscanf(buf, "%99s %d %d %d %ld", 
        name, &y, &m, &d, &money) != 5) {
      // Incorrect format 
      fclose(fp);
      return 3; 
    }

    if ((year == 0 || year == y) && (month == 0 || month == m)) {
      total += money;
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  printf("Total expenditure: %ld\n", total);
  return 0;
}
```

Now call as needed:

```
count_filter(0,0);  All expenditures
count_filter(2022,12);  Just this month
count_filter(2021,0);  Last year
count_filter(0,12);  All Decembers
```